# Display brightness cannot be adjusted 18.04

Tags: display, laptop, brightness, ubuntu-mate, backlight

I have recently installed Ubuntu mate 18.04 on my XPS 15 9560. I cannot adjust the display brightness through any means. I have tried the following:

1. Set the acpi_backlight=vendor in boot parameters
2. used xbacklight, which gives the following results

.

```
xypnox@xypnox-xps:~$ xbacklight -set 50
No outputs have backlight property
```

also I followed another question at [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder), and the output for `sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'` is

```
xypnox@xypnox-xps:~$ sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness_hw_changed
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
/sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to the problem. There display drivers for Ubuntu did not work out of the box for me. I started fresh from a 18.04.1 release and used `nomodeset` to boot into the live USB. Obviously, I could not set the brightness. I installed regularly and rebooted.

I installed the latest nvidia drivers from the ppa: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Then I restarted the system and also added the boot parameters `acpi_rev_override=5 nouveau.runpm=0`.

After the restart the desktop worked fine and I could change between the nvidia and intel graphics and could set my brightness.

Also, updating the kernel did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: This is why the eight answers didn't work: they were focused on `intel_backlight` directory but you had a nVidia problem.

Comment: This is basically the answer, even I tried updating kernel with v5.1, no sucess. Thanks for this one.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative method is to install a PPA and brightness APP which also adjusts gamma - AWESOME!, and ... for any individual screen TOO!

Here are the 3 simple steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

Then find it ...

> Brightness Controller

in  your App's/Accessories

Always Trying to help, Mark

Comment: it works but this won't help you control it using the hardware keys or the in system controls. (at least with the KDE controls)

Comment: I installed 'brightness-controller' on ubuntu 18.04, but it wouldn't completely load when it was launched. The app's GUI was mostly greyed out or missing. I tried rebooting, but no joy.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on a Dell XPS 13. Found this link that solved the problem for me : https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58296#comment168869

What I did:

- changed the content of `/etc/default/grub` by adding `video.only_lcd=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- updated grub with `sudo update-grub`

After restarting the laptop, I was able to control the brightness.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work

Comment: Tried this as well for 9560 but did not work.  On Kernel version 4.15.0

Comment: worked like charm in Sony Vaio. I had same issue after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem some years ago and was having the same problem again after installing ubuntu 18.04. it was a kernel problem then, and i think it may be a kernel problem now.

After updating the kernel the problem was fixed for me.

To update kernel see:
[Updating kernel question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653790/updating-kernel-question)

To download last stable kernel (which worked for me):
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.6/

In my case i downloaded:

```
  linux-headers-4.16.6-041606_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_all.deb

  linux-headers-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb

  linux-image-unsigned-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb

  linux-modules-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb
```

Comment: After download did they install without error using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`? Did you do `apt install -f` afterwards to ensure no errors? Someone else today reported problems with 4.16.3.

Comment: A better link with hundreds of votes for updating latest kernel:https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/307523

Comment: I followed the exact instructions of the link above that you suggested (in particular, I didn't use -f). The packages were installed without errors.

Comment: If you have no errors count yourself lucky I just tried `4.14.38` also released on April 30, 2018 and it still has errors. The OP using `4.16.3` with errors hasn't replied back on his situation yet: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030043/unable-to-upgrade-kernel-after-4-16-3?noredirect=1#comment1674870_1030043 You might want to to post an answer there how `4.16.6` works fine. BTW the hole command to type is `sudo apt install -f` with no package name. It verifies your installation is ok.

Comment: I'll leave a comment there. I was trying to update using the software UKUU and it didn't work. Then I used the terminal following the instructions of the link you suggested and it worked perfectly. Maybe the software has a problem.

Comment: Following WinEunuuchs2Unix suggestion I wrote with more details in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030043/unable-to-upgrade-kernel-after-4-16-3/1030369

Comment: I saw the answer well written. It was a little more than I anticipated which was just confirmation that 4.16.6 works ok for you. Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu** :)

Comment: Thanks. I would rather wait for the kernel to be updated through apt than go for a mainline version because I have been tired of reinstalling Ubuntu, It's the third time now. The display is not at Maximum brightness so its usable enough. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling for the past week on trying to get Ubuntu working on my Dell XPS 15 9570 and I've had it working for a while with nomodeset but it's been killing my eyes having the display stuck on full brightness.

I finally fixed it today! I updated my kernel to 4.17 (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/) which was last updated two days ago and then restarted, and then finally restarted again without the nomodeset option (and didn't have to replace it with anything) and the display works now!!!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the `.deb` files I need to install? I am confused with several options in amd64 and several tutorials only install 3 or 4 out of the provided 7

Comment: I installed the following: linux-headers-4.17.0-041700_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_all.deb, linux-headers-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb, linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb, linux-modules-4.17.0-041700-generic_4.17.0-041700.201806041953_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

I have an XPS 15, and the following solved it for me:

1. Updating to the latest kernel ([4.17.5](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17.5/) is the one I used, following instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/596697))
2. Reboot
3. Remove any video options (`nomodeset`, `video.only_lcd=0`, etc.) from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` file.
4. Run `update-grub` to update
5. Reboot

This made it possible to adjust from the keyboard and made "night mode" actually change screen colors.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous instructions here didn't worked for me
Then I watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BO-kKKi_ERM
and I find out that whole 
Rc.local file was missing.

I created a new file:

printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo -i
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

I removed all and replace new text with these..

ec#!/bin/sh -e
echo 490 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0

Then reboot and it worked

I have Xubuntu 18 and after this brightness came up
a lot, but still it's not in full mode.
I can't adjust it with FN + right/left arrow key. It will
show up but does not go anywhere. Volume adjust with up an down arrow
keys works fine... weird... Xubuntu 18 seems to have bugss..

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the display driver.

My issue is solved with the following steps.
Dell latitude 5590 with intel VGA compatible driver.

1. Installed ubuntu with **nomodeset** option
2. Updated BIOS to 1.2.3
3. Updated /etc/default/grub.

replaced

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.alpha_support=1"
```

and

```
update-grub
```

Comment: That did not work. Moreover the Laptop froze when i removed the nomodeset parameter. Had to readd it.

Comment: As long as nomodeset there, you will not be able to use display settings, so you should try all  grub options without nomodeset.
If you never removed nomodeset, you might want to retry other grub options  again witout nomodeset.

make sure you are using i915 kernel module.
Check your driver's bus info with lshw -C Display.
Then lspci -vv -s bus info after pci@
i.e. lspci -vv -s 0000:00:02.0
Check the Kernel modules. If its other than i915, you should seek the related grub option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isssue and I added `video.only_lcd=0` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT after `quiet splash` in /etc/default/grub then updated grub with `sudo update-grub` rebooted then lcd backlight worked. This was done on a dell xps 14 l421x

Answer (score 0):

On Xubuntu 18.04 (Ubuntu with xfce desktop) my brightness problem finally solved.

I opened 'Onboard Settings' under the 'Settings' menu. If your desktop doesn't have one, you can download it from Software Center.

On the 'Onboard Preferences' window, click the Layout menu, then choose the 'Full Keyboard' (Desktop keyboard with edit and function keys). Click here to view the [Onboard Preferences window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7j8.png)