# Ubuntu 18.04 Live boot leads to blank screen

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 18.04

My system is booting from the USB drive the problem is that after booting it shows the menu to select an option. And on selecting any option it leads to a blank screen.

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB live stick. I waited for about half an hour too after selecting install Ubuntu option, but it's not working.
I have Dell Vostro 3568 8GB RAM, i5 7gen with AMD Radeon. I have made the live USB from startup disk creator which is preinstalled in Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel my system is booting from USB. It is also showing options from grub menu i.e. trying without installing, install ubuntu etc. But on selecting any of the options it leads to a blank screen.

Comment: @karel ok trying mini.iso

Comment: Same happened to me on a Dell XPS 13 9370 as explained @KuldeepPisda

Comment: @karel I got success but half I booted in legacy mode. And was only able to install and I had to change boot option to legacy. Now on loading it hangs to Ubuntu logo screen. And I tried mini.iso file too but it is not even loading.

Comment: I tried that but unable to access any of them. I tried advanced option too but it too sucks after selecting any option either recovery mode or generic. @karel

Comment: Have you [confirmed that the ISO you downloaded isn't corrupted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-10/503788#503788)

Comment: yes @ElderGeek the first thing which I did after facing the problem was that only. And I have figured it out. I got the solution too.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen no it is not the duplicate of that question. I have solved the issue.

Comment: @ElderGeek may you please flag the question as the duplicate of the same.

Comment: @KuldeepPisda for technical reasons I am unable to change my duplicate vote. I could only retract it. Provided that the next reviewer who comes along sees my comment and does their job appropriately, this question will be closed as a duplicate of both of them, steering more people to solutions.

Comment: I had a similar issue installing Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on an AOpen DEX4502. I would only get as far as the empty desktop all paper. It turns out I needed that nomodeset option too. However you can easily enable it from the boot options menu.

* On boot press any key to land in the menu.
* Press F6 to bring up the "Other options" menu.
* Select 'nomodeset'
* Select 'install' or 'start' as you wish

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So after much googling, I got the solution. It was very simple to fix that issue. It is about `nomodeset`.

1. When the USB/CD boots press <kbd>E</kbd> on grub menu it will lead to edit the grub.
2. Find the line which ends with `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` in front of it. So it becomes `nomodeset quiet splash`. Whatever is there in front of it leave it as it is just add `nomodeset` in front of `quiet splash`.

   [image: Grub edit menu]
3. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot it normally. It will lead you to **Try Ubuntu Without installing** option. Now from here too you can install Ubuntu. As **install Ubuntu** option is always there in the live session. Now after installing Ubuntu we need to change `nomodeset` thing permanently so that we don't have to do it again.
4. After successfully installing the system will reboot. Press `shift` button for 5 seconds to get the grub menu after the system starts. If it does not work then try the same with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The most important thing is that it is all about timing.
5. Now again repeat step 2 so that we can login in the system.
6. Now open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` it will be having contents similar to this.

   ```sh
   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```
7. Find the line having `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` in front of it.
8. Now save it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. In order to update grub menu enter:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

[Source and credits](/q/38780)

**Update and Edit 1**

After the above, I was able to boot and install Ubuntu 18.04. I was not able to control screen brightness after installing and setting grub setting as `nomodeset` so after searching on StackOverflow further I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029283/display-brightness-cannot-be-adjusted-18-04) and I also got to know that `nomodeset` is a temporary fix. I updated my kernel and after this, I changed `grub` setting as it was earlier, i. e. removing `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub` and updated `grub`. Now it's working awesome.

*Try [Display brightness cannot be adjusted 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029283/display-brightness-cannot-be-adjusted-18-04) if you face issues such as unable to control screen brightness.*

Comment: So the real fix was to update the kernel after installation? can you specify on how

Comment: @pantos27 yes I have attached that question too. Click on Read Here to read the steps to update the kernel.

Comment: are you using a Dell laptop by chance? if so which kernel did you use?

Comment: @pantos27 yes I am still using a Dell Laptop and my kernel version is 4.16.6-041606-generic

Comment: nomodeset is spelled wrong once however I can't edit since it's only 2 letters.

Comment: @drescherjm where please be specific.

Comment: ***Note: Whatever is there in front of it leave it as it is just add monodeset in front of quiet splash***

Comment: I wonder why it is not so by default and they make people waste precious time guessing whats wrong ... anyway thanks for posting!

Comment: Before updating kernel version try with Nvidia drivers from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1083714/971854

It worked for me. It solved both the blank screen and the brightness control issue