# Tries to install Ubuntu, but gets kernel panic message

Tags: boot, kernel

My computer crashes after an update. Used windows 7 at the time. I tried to install win 8.1 instead and do a clean install. Managed to install win 8.1 but after the reboot the computer got into a loop and could not get past.

I tried everything I could to solve it. But just did not go. Then a friend suggested installing Ubuntu instead. Then followed the instructions to install Ubuntu. But when ubuntu boots, I may choose to test ubuntu or install ubuntu etc. When I press install I get a black screen with text. Even when I press test ubuntu. Boot from a USB-stick.

[Wrong message I get](https://imgshare.io/image/J3TJQ)

Have tested this solution without any positive result.

[Ubuntu 18.04 Live boot leads to blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029624/ubuntu-18-04-live-boot-leads-to-blank-screen)[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQbUY.jpg)

Sorry, if english is not the best grammatically speaking. But run google translate. Are from Sweden.

Please help me :)

Is there any more information you need, then just write them. So I'll try to give it to you.

Comment: The image you uploaded is ***tiny*** and not readable.

Comment: now it is resolved

Comment: This sounds like hardware issue [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1448312) could be informative. If it is hardware compatibility, try a different kernel. If it is hardware failure, fix it. It is worth trying to perform a memory test to rule out memory failure.

Comment: I will look into that! Thx. I have done a memory test and ruled that out