# Ubuntu 20.04 Hangs when "Try ubuntu" on install

Tags: boot, nvidia, intel-graphics, 20.04, dual-graphics

When I boot an external HDD (fat32) and click on "Try Ubuntu", the system hangs, it has no cursor and the hard drive is doing nothing, I have no choice than to hard shutdown the laptop.

I have a Windows boot partition on an SSD, maybe it is the problem here? I checked for a "Fast boot" option in the BIOS but it does not exist nor a "Secure boot".

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 as a GPU and an Intel HD Graphics 630 integrated video chip.

Comment: The most common culprits for the issue you describe are your video card or GPU -- please add details about those to your question above. The "Try Ubuntu" environment does not read your HDD or SSD (they are not even mounted) so those are unlikely to be causes.

Comment: Although this is unrelated to your current issue, fastboot is a Windows option and you will need to disable this in your Windows settings before you install Ubuntu. Open Windows, find the fastboot setting, disable it, and power off (fully shut down and do not hibernate).

Comment: **After you disable fastboot and fully shut down windows**, you can [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167115) to boot or **If you are selecting "try Ubuntu" from a grub menu**, please [follow these instructions instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030674/167115). However, I can't stress enough how important it is that you disable fastboot before you begin because Ubuntu will not recognize the Windows partition if you don't. Also, it's a good idea to make a backup and a backup Windows installation media before you begin just in case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

I tried "Install ubuntu (safe graphics)" in grub and it worked