# Ubuntu 18.04, Unable to change screen resolution with NVIDIA graphic card

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, display-resolution

This is a bit long but pretty straight forward:

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB key but instead of the grub menu I kept getting a burnt-out screen.

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029624/ubuntu-18-04-live-boot-leads-to-blank-screen) I understood that my NVIDIA graphic card is the problem, I'd edited the **USB key** grub menu and added the nomodeset flag. While this did work when I tried to access the installation I got the burnt-out screen again.

Long story short, I did the same (with nomodeset flag) with a 16.04 USB key and then upgraded to 18.04.

The problem now is that the resolution is stuck on very low and I cannot change it. I tried to remove the nomodeset flag from the grub but it isn't even there anymore.

I am guessing that it is still something to do with the NVIDIA drivers but it is way over my head and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I need just a little more work to figure it out.

To add NVIDIA drivers repository I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

But I could not understand how to choose the driver I needed.
I started by finding out what driver I needed from NVIDIA's website here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Then I opened Ubuntu's Software & Updates, went to the tab named 'Additional drivers' and allows a couple of minutes for it to fetch the relevant drivers. 
Then its just a matter of selecting the right driver, selecting 'Apply changes' and rebooting the system.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer in two days. Thanks.