# Monitor resolution problem when installing ubuntu server

Tags: display, display-resolution

I’ve tried using multiple monitors to install ubuntu server, i was able to boot it and i reached a screen saying test/install ubuntu server. After pressing enter some lines showed up and errors messages like “The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display.Please change your input timing to 1366x768@60Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications “ on a dell monitor and “not optimum mode” on Samsung monitors.I don’t know how to proceed.please help

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS or install you server computer with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem (although the message had a different resolution). I needed to install Ubuntu 22.04 from USB to a Dell PowerEdge T550 Server and it only has a VGA port. When I selected "Ubuntu" from the boot menu, I would not see the welcome screen, but would get an error message from the monitor about the resolution.

I finally tried the second selection in the list "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" and I got the Welcome Screen inviting me to "Try" or "Install". I am able to install, but on the reboot I got the same error about the monitor resolution. I found that the grub option `nomodeset` is the same as "Safe Graphics".

It's a bit tricky, because you need to update `/etc/default/grub` and then run `upgrade-grub` on the installed system (`update-grub` will generate a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file).

Here's how I did it:

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04 using "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" option
2. Boot from a live USB (similar to "Install" but instead select "Try").
3. Once it boots, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and mount your Ubuntu partition on `/mnt`. I’m assuming the Ubuntu partition is `/dev/sda2`, but you should determine this yourself. (If you go on the file manager and select "Other Locations" it will show you the hard drive is `/dev/sdaX`):

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

4. Edit `/mnt/etc/default/grub` Modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` so that it reads:

```sh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

5. Mount dependencies:

```sh
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev  
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc  
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys  
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts  
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

6. Change the root from the USB to the HDD:

```sh
sudo chroot /mnt
```

7. Update the grub configuration:

```sh
sudo update-grub
```

8. Reboot

References:

- https://stackallflow.com/ubuntu/how-to-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd-in-ubuntu/
- [What do the nomodeset, quiet and splash kernel parameters mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 Live boot leads to blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029624/ubuntu-18-04-live-boot-leads-to-blank-screen/1030674#1030674)
- [What is safe graphics mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138137/what-is-safe-graphics-mode)

Comment: As an alternative, you could install an SSH server as part of your installation and use this instead of the `chroot`.