# ubuntu server 22.04 LTS - Installer Resolution not Supported

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation, display-resolution, 22.04

Issue:
Fresh new install using Server 22.04 LTS X86_64 ISO downloaded 2022/05/16 will boot installer into a 'Graphics Mode/RefreshRate' not supported by my monitors (3 VGA monitors tried) on a DELL R610 host with VGA output only.

I've edited Grub Command 'e' and changed the 'set gfxpayload=keep' to 'set gfxpayload=text' which helps on the kernel info logging, but when the Installer runs, it switches to a Resolution/Refresh Rate not supported by my monitors

Is it possible to issue grub command values to set it to good old safe settings like Server 20.04 LTS?  (20.04 LTS Server boot to installer works ok on same silicon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitor resolution problem when installing ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404416/monitor-resolution-problem-when-installing-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 3):

At GRUB2

- Select *Try or Install Ubuntu*
- Press *Edit (`e`)*
- Add `nomodeset` to the `linux` line such that it looks as follows:

  ```
  linux /casper/vmlinuz nomodeset ---
  ```
- Press `F10` (Boot)
- Profit!  (At least it gets you into the Installer)