# Ubuntu Server 22.04 Display Timings Error on Installation

Tags: server, grub2, display, display-resolution, 22.04

In trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 Server on a Dell R6515, following error is reported.

"The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1200@60Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications."

The above error occurs on multiple monitors, while other monitor simply display a blank screen at this step. The server has only two VGA ports, and both yield the same result.

USB install drive with Ubuntu 22.04 Server

PowerEdge R6515

Bios 2.3.6

DHCP

Only two options are shown in Grub:

*Try or Install Unbuntu Server

Test Memory

This question suggests using "Ubuntu (safe graphics)", but this is not an option. [Monitor resolution problem when installing ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404416/monitor-resolution-problem-when-installing-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) provided a method to get through this problem.

On the selection to `Try` or `Install Ubuntu`, hit <kbd>e</kbd> to get to the Grub menu.
In the line that starts with `linux`, add `nomodeset` to the end of the line.
This setting will provide a usable display.