# What application or library in ubuntu 18.04 allows the media keys on a laptop for adjusting screen brightness to work?

Tags: keyboard, brightness, desktop-environments, media-buttons

The brightness adjustment keys on my laptop work out-of-the-box on ubuntu 18.04's default desktop environment.  When I install a new desktop environment, they no longer work.  I'm able to install additional software to restore that functionality, but I want to know what library or application in ubuntu's default installation controls screen brightness.

This is not a duplicate of [How do I adjust screen brightness when using a different environment from GNOME/Unity on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032945/27113) because I want to know specifically what ubuntu 18.04 is mapping the screen brightness adjustment keys to by default.

Answer (score 0):

On Xubuntu 18.04 (Ubuntu with xfce desktop) my brightness problem finally solved.

I opened 'Onboard Settings' under the 'Settings' menu. If your desktop doesn't have one, you can download it from Software Center.

On the 'Onboard Preferences' window, click the Layout menu, then choose the 'Full Keyboard' (Desktop keyboard with edit and function keys). Click here to view the [Onboard Preferences window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7j8.png)