# Bightness regulation Dell Inspirion 5593

Tags: 18.04, brightness, backlight

I have a Dell Ispirion 5593, with a NVIDIA GPU and an i7-1065G7 CPU and I can't regulate the brightness of the screen using the <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> keys, as I can do in Windows. I also made an attempt to solve the problem by installing `brightness-controller`, which wasn't effective at all.
Then I tried to set:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, after `quiet splash`, but any of this changes was effective.

**Edit**

The solutions proposed in [this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029283/display-brightness-cannot-be-adjusted-18-04) seem to be not effective in my case. In particular, I tried to set `video.only_lcd=0` and to use `brightness-controller`.

The folder `/sys/class/backlight` **is empty**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display brightness cannot be adjusted 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029283/display-brightness-cannot-be-adjusted-18-04)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No, unfortunately brightness-controller is not effective in my case

Comment: as well as video.only_lcd=0