# Is there a command to replicate the screen gradually dimming before locking?

Tags: nvidia, screen, brightness

I would like to be able to adjust my monitor's brightness via the keyboard without use of `xrandr`. The reason for this is that I have a custom NVIDIA color profile, and using `xrandr` resets it.

What I've tried:

- Running a script which uses `xrandr` to make the adjustment, and then reloads my NVIDIA color profile. This does not work because any change made to the color settings will shoot the brightness up to max.

Just before locking, there appears to be an overlay placed over the screen. I realized that replicating this could be a solution to my problem, but I have no idea how to go about doing so.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223338/brightness-alters-between-0-and-100?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029283/display-brightness-cannot-be-adjusted-18-04?rq=1 would help, I hope.