# Brightness nvidia quadro M1200

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP zbook studio g4. This laptop comes with a nvidia quadro M1200 and is enabled in the BIOS as dedicated card.

I have found this answer: [Backlight not working on Ubuntu 17.10, Lenovo P51, Xorg, NVIDIA Quadro M1200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977353/backlight-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10-lenovo-p51-xorg-nvidia-quadro-m1200)

But this worked not for me. The xbacklight does not respond when I do this in the terminal:

```
xbacklight =50
```

Then I tried to get the value which is the backlight at the moment, to see if the package responded:

```
xbacklight -get
```

but then there was no response.

The package is installed using

```
sudo apt install xbacklight
```

So I assumed that that is what I need to do.

I tried everything after a reboot after the grub was changed and the package was installed.

Is there someone who found already a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem some years ago and was having the same problem again after installing ubuntu 18.04. it was a kernel problem then, and i think it may be a kernel problem now.

after updating the kernel the problem was fixed for me.

to update kernel see:
[Updating kernel question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653790/updating-kernel-question)

to download last stable kernel (which worked for me):
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.6/

in my case i downloaded:

linux-headers-4.16.6-041606_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_all.deb

linux-headers-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb

linux-image-unsigned-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb

linux-modules-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb

Comment: Note that switching to the upstream "stable kernels" is the same as being on the Mainline kernels; you do this at your own risk, and your mileage may vary with regards to success.  (This is usually only done as a 'debugging' step to determine if the issue is in the current kernel on the system, and these don't usually receive any updates at all later for security or other issues)

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the information! I prefer using "ubuntu's standard kernel", but it is not working well in my computer.

Comment: Following a suggestion I wrote with more details in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030043/unable-to-upgrade-kernel-after-4-16-3/1030369

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I just found this morning my own solution without switching kernels (which I prefer to make sure I receive updates). I had to enable the nvidia driver from "software &updates".  In the tab "additional drivers" I choose there NVIDIA instead of X.org X server. Now I can use the command "xbacklight", and I think it is possible to assign the command to the keyboard as shortcuts, but at the moment I just use the command in the terminal.