# Unable to upgrade kernel after 4.16.3

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.16.3 Kernel, both on my desktop and laptop, every time I try to upgrade to a newer kernel with UKUU fails the configuration of the package and return me this error (example installing 4.16.6):

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.16.6-041606-generic (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

And the only solution is to remove it, how can i solve it?

Comment: 4.16.4 has a bug. Same as 4.14.36.

Comment: so we should just wait a working relase?

Comment: Yeah but you can't add any other programs until `apt install -f` is fixed.

Comment: It won't let you remove it either. I'll post an answer after work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## October 28, 2018 Update

For dkms support of nVidia, bbswitch and virtual box compiling use:

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

To circumvent newer `linux-header` installation errors download: [libssl1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libssl1.1/download)

Download the [newer kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) you want and your `~/Downloads` should look like this:

```
$ ll *.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  1128420 Oct 28 08:33 libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 10741128 Oct 28 08:05 linux-headers-4.14.78-041478_4.14.78-041478.201810200529_all.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  1052200 Oct 28 08:05 linux-headers-4.14.78-041478-generic_4.14.78-041478.201810200529_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  8243552 Oct 28 08:05 linux-image-unsigned-4.14.78-041478-generic_4.14.78-041478.201810200529_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 47559380 Oct 28 08:06 linux-modules-4.14.78-041478-generic_4.14.78-041478.201810200529_amd64.deb
```

Now you should be able to successfully install:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

---

## Original Answer

Kernels `4.14.xx`, `4.16.xx` and `4.17.rc(xx)` all share the same bug over this last week; April 24-30, 2018.

I just tried `4.14.38` tonight and it exhibits the same errors as `4.14.36` and `4.14.37` as documented in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-base/+bug/1766851).

In my case tonight the errors are:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.14.38-041438.
(Reading database ... 641792 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.14.38-041438_4.14.38-041438.201804300419_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.14.38-041438 (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic_4.14.38-041438.201804300419_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic_4.14.38-041438.201804300419_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic_4.14.38-041438.201804300419_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.14.38-041438 (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic:
 linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.postinst: 50: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.postinst: linux-update-symlinks: not found
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.14.38-041438-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic
```

To fix errors I tried `sudo apt install -f` but it won't fix it plus causes a "crash report":

[image: Kernel 4.14.38 crash.png]

Using [`sudo rm-kernels`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077) I removed `4.14.38` as much as I could:

[image: remove 4.14.38 kernel]

This time around only the headers were successfully removed:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.14.38-041438*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 74.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 665813 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.14.38-041438 (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.postinst: 50: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.postinst: linux-update-symlinks: not found
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now let's see what is left over:

```
$ apt list | grep 4.14.36

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-unsigned-4.14.36-041436-generic/now 4.14.36-041436.201804240906 amd64 [residual-config]
```

Let's try to remove it:

```
$ sudo apt remove linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms gdm libjansson4 libxnvctrl0 linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008
  linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1009 linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp linux-tools-4.10.0-1009-gcp nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  python-compizconfig python-pyudev screen-resolution-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 296 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 641771 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.prerm: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.prerm: linux-check-removal: not found
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic depends on linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic.

Removing linux-modules-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.prerm`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

version=4.14.38-041438-generic
image_path=/boot/vmlinuz-$version
    (... SNIP ...)
```

Just below the first line `#!/bin/sh` insert a new line:

```
exit 0
```

Save the file and rerun the failed command:

```
$ sudo apt remove linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms gdm libjansson4 libxnvctrl0 linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008
  linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1009 linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp linux-tools-4.10.0-1009-gcp nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  python-compizconfig python-pyudev screen-resolution-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 8,663 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 635588 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic (4.14.38-041438.201804300419) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.14.38-041438-generic.postrm ... removing pending trigger
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.14.38-041438-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /home/rick/Pictures/1600x900/19.jpg
Found background image: /home/rick/Pictures/1600x900/19.jpg
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.34-041434-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.34-041434-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.31-041431-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.31-041431-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.30-041430-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.30-041430-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.27-041427-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.27-041427-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.15-041415-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.15-041415-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.10-041410-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.10-041410-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.4-041404-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.4-041404-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.2-041402-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.14.2-041402-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.9-041309-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.9-041309-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.77-040977-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.77-040977-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.53-031653-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.53-031653-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p8
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Double check everything is ok:

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms gdm libjansson4 libxnvctrl0 linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008
  linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1009 linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp linux-tools-4.10.0-1009-gcp nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  python-compizconfig python-pyudev screen-resolution-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 7):

Using ukuu to install kernels past v4.16.3 required these steps

1. install libssl1.1 from
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libssl1.1/download
2. install the matching linux-modules deb for the kernel

For example for the 4.16.7 kernel grab the linux-module deb from

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.7/

You can find your kernel at -->
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: I had to install libssl1.1 from bionic to upgrade my kernel from v4.14.37 to v4.14.41 earlier today in an artful installation.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel that came with Ubuntu 18.04 has brightness problems for my computer (Lenovo IdeaPad S400). This was solved updating the kernel version.

I was trying earlier to update the kernel to version 4.16.6 using the software UKUU and it didn't work. Then I followed the instructions in (using the terminal): [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

For my computer I downloaded the following packages (in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16.6/):

1. `linux-headers-4.16.6-041606_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_all.deb`
2. `linux-headers-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb`
3. `linux-image-unsigned-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb`
4. `linux-modules-4.16.6-041606-generic_4.16.6-041606.201804300418_amd64.deb`

Then, following the instructions of the link above, I wrote:

```
cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! This is very straightforward and it has helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I've been experiencing with the latest series of Linux kernels (that is those after K4.16.3> ) is that the "linux-image.deb" files are NOT signed. It is the lack of signed binary files that is causing all the problems i.e. fails to install, system just borks at any attempts.

The only solution IMO is to hold back and wait patiently for the next major kernel release i.e. K.4.17 or even K5.0 in the hope that the required linux-imge.deb files will include the necessary key signing and thus install without any difficulties.

Cyteck